# Carousel in android

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am doing an android project using carousel.It should have different images while sliding..My project needs to have multiple carousel in a single page..how am i supposed to do that..I have already searched net and tried almost all links...but nothing is what I am looking for..So please help me in the following

- How to use different images in a carousel
- How to use multiple vertical carousel in a single page

Can somebody please help me?

This is a fragment of the code I am using

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);

    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);

    // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
    // directions left and right
    pager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

    // Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    // Set margin for pages as a negative number, so a part of next and
    // previous pages will be showed
    pager.setPageMargin(-200);
```

Comment: hey are you still looking for answer  ? please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CarouselPicker library as follows
Add this in your root build.gradle file at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add the dependency :

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.GoodieBag:CarouselPicker:v1.1'
    }
```

XML Carousel to your layout

```
<in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CCC"
        app:items_visible="three" />
```

Java code to populate the carousel

```
CarouselPicker carouselPicker = (CarouselPicker) findViewById(R.id.carousel);

    // Case 1 : To populate the picker with images
    List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    imageItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.i1));
    imageItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.i2));
    imageItems.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.i3));
    //Create an adapter
    CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this, imageItems, 0);
    //Set the adapter
    carouselPicker.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

And the listeners:

```
carouselPicker.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //position of the selected item
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

You can find the documentetion at https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker.

A usefull and easy to follow tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTJm1Ys9jMI